# Where does KDE Plasma store the user-specified arrangement of desktop icons?

Tags: kde, icons, desktop-icons

Ubuntu 20.04, with KDE installed on top. --
KDE Plasma 5.18.5

The way I organize some things means I've invested a lot of effort and embedded a lot of useful information in the actual arrangement of icons on my desktop. For example, arranging icons for programs according to the category of program, or using one section as a to-do list, with the most urgent folders to the left and less urgent to the right.

But I'm also using multiple monitors, and if anything goes wrong with one of them, KDE will move all my icons to the primary monitor. Which is good in the moment -- at least I can still access them while the other monitor is offline. It doesn't move icons *back* into place when the monitor is back online, though. They remain on the primary screen until I manually move them back one by one and rebuild the previous arrangement.

One clunky and labor-intensive way of fixing this is to have a screenshot of the way it used to be and then manually rebuild the arrangement to match the screenshot.

But I'm looking to do this a better way. *Somewhere* in KDE, there must be a file that actually stores the arrangement of desktop icons, probably as a list with an x and y value for each one. If I could find that file, I could set up a cron job to automatically make regular backups of it, and then if anything messes up the arrangement, I could just replace that file with the one from my backups, refresh the desktop, and everything should snap right back into place, right back where it was, like magic.

But does anybody know *where* this file might be?

Comment: On Kubuntu 22.10 and Plasma 5.25 this issue still appears to be there. I heard it should be getting better by 5.27, so hoping for that. The icon position info is stored at ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc - but saving and restoring that file did not help me, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

It's the file
~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc

Inside `[Containments][NUMBER][General]`

In `positions=` with the grid order of each icon, `0, 0` being top left.

Credit goes to [skjerns](https://askubuntu.com/users/1362027/skjerns).